# GCP Https Function - Ingress settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have one GCP Https function. This function will be invoked either by other GCP function(Pub/Sub) or from the external application.

I want my function should be accessible from these 2 sources only. By default, my function ingress setting is "Allow All Traffic".

How can I achieve this so that my function should be accessible only from one specific external IP. I am beginner in cloud technology so I may have missed something.

Comment: Pub/Sub does not provide a static IP address. Cloud Functions does not provide a firewall. Instead, Functions uses OIDC Identity Tokens for authorization. Your goal of using  IP addresses for authorization will not support your requirements.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am using authorization with role. But it means anyone from any ip can call function and then Authentication process will check whether request is valid or not. But I don't want this. I think cloud armor and load balancer will work. I am checking this.

Comment: What do you mean by **authorization with role**? OIDC Identity Tokens do not have roles. The resource can grant permissions based on identity. If you mean you are using Access Tokens granting IAM roles for admin type commands, then you cannot block them with a firewall, load balancer, etc. Edit your question with details.

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley 
Sorry for the confusion. 
The runtime for both the functions (pub/sub and https) is project_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. 
When https function invoked by pub/sub function, it works as expected.

But I want to invoke https function in the same manner from outside. My understanding for authorization with role is using runtime service account for both the funcions.
Now, using cloud armour and load balancer I can invoke https function from outside too.

From the below answer, I am reading GFE and how to use it for https function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering by the IP address is not the recommend way. Using authentication (with IAM service that check the authorization) is a much better solution. *Your IPs can change, you can use a VPN, or whatever. Network can change not your identity*

When you use Cloud Functions native authentication filtering (with IAM service) and makes your cloud function private, anyone can access it from the internet. BUT, before reaching your Cloud Functions, the traffic is checked by GFE (Google Front End) that control the authentication token presence, validity and IAM permission.

ONLY is all the condition are met, your Cloud Functions is invoked. I feel the fear in your comment that anyone can invoke your functions and it will cost a lot. With private functions, only authorized traffic is routed to your functions (and therefore paid). All the bad traffic is discarded by Google for you.

---

If you really want to enforce your pattern, you can do the following:

- set the ingress to "internal and cloud load balancing"
- Add a VPC connector to your other GCP function with the egress set to ALL (to route all the traffic through your VPC)
- Create a HTTPS load balancer with a serverless NEG that reference your Cloud Functions
- Activate Cloud Armor on your load balancer with a rule that filter only the IP that you want.

Heavy, boring and expensive (you have to pay the load balancer, $14 per month) for nothing more than identity check. Prefer the first solution ;)

Comment: The solution implemented by me was using Armour and load balancer. I am trying to understand your first solution but not getting as I am beginner in cloud. Can you share the steps or any document for implementing this solution.

Comment: In fact the first solution does not rely on the network, but on the identity of the requester. If the requester has the permission he can access the function, if not, the request is discarded at no cost for you. For that, remove "allUsers" from your function permission or deploy it with the parameter `--noallow-unauthenticated`. And grant the role functions.invoker to the identity (user or service account) that have to access the cloud function